# What is the most convenient way to change options for Graph[] objects?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, version-8

What is the most convenient way to change options such as `VertexLabels` in existing `Graph` objects?  (Version 7 users note: `Graph` is new in Mathematica 8.)

---

With graphics, we can use `Show` for this, not matter what function was originally used to produce the graphic:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Show[g, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

Is there an analogous function for `Graph`s?  Suppose we already have a graph, and now we need to show vertex labels in a different way.

Here's a workaround using `HighlightGraph`:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2}]
HighlightGraph[g, {}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

While it works, this is not really what `HighlightGraph` is meant for.

---

Please note that `Graph` objects are atomic before trying to take them apart. Also, I'm looking for the safest and most robust solution. I'm hoping there's a function I overlooked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `SetProperty`. For example

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4}]

SetProperty[g, VertexLabels -> {"Name", 2 -> "Two"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Szabolcs, Heike Unfortunately (and unlike `Show`), `SetProperty` does not work if there is no second argument, which is a PITA if ypou want to make a wrapper function and call it with no options: `Options[plotGraph] = Options@Graph;
plotGraph[g_Graph, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := SetProperty[g, opts]; g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}];plotGraph[g]`. So one has to check whether `opts` is empty or not...

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Graph` itself much like `Show`. However, you pass the essential data from the graph as the first argument, rather than the graph itself.  (`Graph[g,....]` will not work.)

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 8, 1 -> 11, 1 -> 18, 1 -> 19, 1 -> 21, 1 -> 25, 1 -> 26}, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    ImagePadding -> 10]

Graph[EdgeList[g], VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond", VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image: graphs]

Special types of graphs, e.g. `TreeGraph`, `AdjacencyGraph`, `IncidenceGraph`, etc. should work in a similar fashion.

---

**Edit**

Heike's solution has the advantage of maintaining the original options of the graph:

```
SetProperty[g, VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond"]
```

[image: graph2]

It's nice that the `VertexName`s are displayed as they were initially in `g` (in contrast to the second graph shown above).

Comment: Strange, on my version of Mathematica setting `VertexSize` works fine, e.g. `SetProperty[g, {VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond", VertexSize -> Large}]`.

Comment: When I cut and paste your code, `SetProperty[g, {VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond", VertexSize -> Large}]`, into Mathematica, it works fine. However, when I type it into my notebook, it does not.  Seems like there is some sort of corruption in my notebook.

Comment: @David, is it possible that you forgot to put the options into a list when typing `SetProperty[g, {VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond", VertexSize -> Large}]` manually?  I made that mistake when I first typed it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes. I forgot the braces. (Actually, I didn't know that `SetProperty` required a list for multiple properties.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 10, the following works:

```
Graph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Here `g` is already a graph object.

This syntax is important because it also allows converting between `Graph` and `Graph3D`, both of which are graphs, but the latter is displayed in 3D by default.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a few cases where `SetProperty` is useless, for example one cannot set `GraphLayout` (as discovered by Szabolcs [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4546/89)) or `VertexLabels`, and possibly more:

```
SetProperty[Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "A"}], VertexLabels -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Solution

I offer a more robust solution that explicitly replaces options. It keeps properties, keeps and updates existing options and adds new options. It might not be the fastest when it comes to rebuilding huge graphs, as it has to extract vertices and edges.

```
Options[showGraph] = Options@Graph;
showGraph[g_] := g;
showGraph[g_Graph, {new___}] := showGraph[g, new];
showGraph[g_Graph, new : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{old = Options@g, opts},
   opts = DeleteDuplicates[First /@ Join[old, {new}]];
   Graph[VertexList@g, EdgeList@g, Thread[opts -> (opts /. {new} /. old)]]];
```

### Testing

```
{g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, ImageSize -> 120, ImagePadding -> 15, 
   VertexSize -> {2 -> Large}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"},
    GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold", EdgeStyle -> {(1 -> 2) -> Red}, 
   GraphLayout -> "SpiralEmbedding"],
 showGraph[g, EdgeStyle -> {(1 -> 2) -> Green}, VertexLabels -> None, 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"],
 showGraph[g],
 showGraph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately, something like `showGraph[Graph[v_, e_, old_]]:=Graph[v, e, ...]` won't work, as:

```
MatchQ[Graph[{1, 2}, {1 -> 2}], _[_, _, ___]]   (* ==> False *)
MatchQ[graph[{1, 2}, {1 -> 2}], _[_, _, ___]]   (* ==> True  *)
```

One of the million annoying features of the atomistic representation of `Graph`-s.