# How to recompute the layout of a Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I [asked a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4543/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-change-options-for-graph-objects) about changing `Graph` properties in a similar way to how `Show` can change `Graphics` properties.  The answer was to use `SetProperty`.

Unfortunately this does not work for `GraphLayout`.  Take the following example:

```
g1 = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]
g2 = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]

{PropertyValue[g1, GraphLayout], PropertyValue[g2, GraphLayout]}

(* ==> {Automatic, "SpringEmbedding"} *)

ng1 = SetProperty[g1, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
ng2 = SetProperty[g2, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]

{PropertyValue[ng1, GraphLayout], PropertyValue[ng2, GraphLayout]}

(* ==> {Automatic, "SpringEmbedding"} *)
```

Note that while `GraphLayout` can be queried through the standard property API, it doesn't seem like it can be set.  Again, a hack like `HighlightGraph[g, {}, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]` will work, but it is just a hack.

One could retrieve the vertex and edge lists of the graph and build a new `Graph[...]`, but that is both tedious and it'll discard other property values.

**So, what is the best way to re-layout a graph?**

Right-clicking the graph and choosing a new layout works, but I'm looking for a programmatic way.  Also, right-clicking and choosing a new layout is *terribly slow*---much much slower than rebuilding the graph or using `HighlighGraph` (can anyone reproduce this problem, is it slow for you as well?)

**Update**

Some spelunking reveals that `` GraphComputation`CloneGraph[g, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"] `` will do the job, but I'd rather not use internal and undocumented functionality for this.

Comment: To clarify: I'm not looking to just just visualize a graph, so `GraphPlot` is not appropriate here.  I want to re-layout it using the new `Graph` functionality, and also retrieve the coordinates.

Comment: I cannot confirm slow speed for right-click layouting. This seems to work with the same speed as a rebuild with different layout. This is on Win 7 64bit with a quadcore Intel i7 CPU with 16GB RAM.

Comment: @Yves I have a single-core CPU here, I suspect it has to do soemthing with the slowness.  I get a "spinner" that runs for a long time before the new layout is shown.

Comment: If you have a particularly nasty graph please share. I tried with your examples and some rather larger ones - all worked speedily. Time for new hardware?

Comment: This seems to change the "layout": PropertyValue[g1, Properties] = {"GraphProperties" -> {GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"}}; But the image doesn't reconfigure itself.

Comment: I am not sure if you noticed that I added an answer to this old question.

Comment: In version 11.2.0, `{PropertyValue[ng1, GraphLayout], PropertyValue[ng2, GraphLayout]}` gives  `{"CircularEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding"}` as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have a graph with quite a few complex custom properties - below every edge and vertex have their unique properties:

```
g = Graph[Table[Style[j, Hue[j/2^8 - 1]], {j, 0, 2^8 - 1}], 
  Table[Style[j \[UndirectedEdge] FromDigits[Drop[IntegerDigits[j, 2], 1], 2], 
    Hue[j/2^8]], {j, 0, 2^8 - 1}], GraphLayout -> "RadialDrawing", 
  GraphStyle -> "LargeNetwork"]
```

[image]

To keep these properties and change the `GraphLayout`:

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString[InputForm[g]], "RadialDrawing" -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Alternatively you could just use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and retype the `GraphLayout` option.

Yet another alternative, which avoids potentially unsafe string replacements, is the following:

```
ReleaseHold[
 ToExpression[ToString[InputForm[g]], InputForm, Hold] /. 
  "RadialDrawing" -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"
]
```

This converts the `Graph` object to a non-atomic Mathematica expression with the head `Graph`.  Since this expression is not [atomic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html), standard expression manipulation functions, including `ReplaceAll`, can be used on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  You're working around the fact that `Graph` is not an atomic object by converting it to `InputForm` as a string. That's a nice idea though manipulating code as string makes me a little uneasy ... Are you sure that all of the properties of the graph are preserved when converting to input form (they are in my limited test)?

Comment: @Szabolcs It is a trick, but string processing is quite robust. If you look at the `InputForm` output in the above case, you'll see it is not small, yet it works. This is basically programmatic code editing, which is a general approach.

Comment: I'm a bit uncomfortable with changing code in the string representation ... suppose for example that we need to replace `Ticks` with something else.  When using a string repersentation, it's not so easy to tell apart `Ticks` from `FrameTicks` without starting to write a rudimentary parsers.  More importantly, it's all too easy to miss these little details and not think of an edge case where string replacement may lead to undesirable results.

Comment: Perhaps instead of doing string replacement, we could improve your approach to get the graph representation as an actual expression: `ToExpression[ToString@InputForm[g], InputForm, Hold]`  Then `ReplaceAll` what needs to be replaced and `ReleaseHold`.  What do you think?  If you think it's a good idea, could you edit it into the answer (or would you mind if I did)?  Then I'll accept.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure, if you find a more robust way - please go ahead and edit.

Answer (score 3):

I posted a way to update options of `Graph` objects like `Show` works for `Graphics` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37810/89), could you please confirm whether this is a solution for your needs with recomputing the layout?

```
Options[showGraph] = Options@Graph;
showGraph[g_] := g;
showGraph[g_Graph, {new___}] := showGraph[g, new];
showGraph[g_Graph, new : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{old = Options@g, opts},
   opts = DeleteDuplicates[First /@ Join[old, {new}]];
   Graph[VertexList@g, EdgeList@g, Thread[opts -> (opts /. {new} /. old)]]
   ];
```

It simply replaces existing option values with new ones and adds new options, while maintaining the first two arguments of `Graph` without change. Using Vitaliy's example:

```
g1 = Graph[Table[Style[j, Hue[j/2^8 - 1]], {j, 0, 2^8 - 1}], 
   Table[Style[
     j <-> FromDigits[Drop[IntegerDigits[j, 2], 1], 2], 
     Hue[j/2^8]], {j, 0, 2^8 - 1}], GraphLayout -> "RadialDrawing", 
   GraphStyle -> "LargeNetwork", ImageSize -> 300];
g2 = showGraph[g1, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"];

Column@{{g1, PropertyValue[g1, GraphLayout]}, {g2, 
   PropertyValue[g2, GraphLayout]}}
PropertyValue[g1, VertexCoordinates]
PropertyValue[g2, VertexCoordinates]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

If you know the options you want to preserve, you can explicitly list them and change the ones you want to alter through `ReplaceAll`:

```
ng1 = g1;
a = AbsoluteOptions[g1, {GraphLayout, DirectedEdges, EdgeLabelStyle, EdgeLabels, 
      GraphRoot, Properties, VertexLabels, VertexShape,  VertexLabelStyle}] 
   /. {(GraphLayout -> _) -> GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"};
Graph[Join[VertexList[g1],EdgeList[g1]], a]
```

This is admittedly a bit clunky, but I cannot find a simpler way.

You can't simply grab all of the `AbsoluteOptions`. For example, in the default options, `EdgeShapeFunction-> $Failed`, returned by `AbsoluteOptions`, will cause `Graph` to fail.  I'm not sure whether there is such a thing as a universal list of desirable graph properties.

Comment: Yep, this is the simple way I'd like to avoid because it loses other information, e.g. vertex sizes or highlighting.  Obtaining the vertex coordinates is fortunately easy, as you say.  It also works with `PropertyValue`

Comment: @belisarius How did you discover the right hand side of the rule? `AbsoluteOptions[g1, EdgeShapeFunction]` returns `EdgeShapeFunction -> $Failed`

Comment: @Szabolcs  You are correct. I updated my answer aiming to recover some of the likely missing information. Take a look.

Comment: @David **AbsoluteOption[g1]** just plain

Comment: And there are SEVERAL bugs there

Comment: @belisarius  My first reaction was also to use `AbsoluteOptions[g1]` plain, but MMA would not process the information correctly; it even refused to provide a graph.  One of the difficulties arose because of `EdgeShapeFunction-> $failed`.  I am puzzled.

Comment: @David run this one http://ideone.com/pi8hK

Comment: @belisarius I ran it. It did not work. More troubling is that I could not understand the code. Perhaps after a night's sleep it will look clearer to me.

Comment: @David Sleep well! And don't mind it too much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an explanation why the properties route doesn't work. I suspect that `GraphLayout` is an *option* of the Graph, and not a *property*. While it is possible to introduce an inert *property* named `GraphLayout` using

```
PropertyValue[g, Properties] = {"GraphProperties" -> 
                                    {GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"}}
```

as amr suggests, this doesn't set the *option*:

```
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"];

FullForm[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PropertyValue[g, Properties] = {"GraphProperties" -> 
                                    {GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"}}

FullForm[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Strange that `PropertyValue` can *read* the option name too though.

Comment: @Szabolcs True. I'm a bit stymied. In all examples  of the  properties talk is only about vertex and edge properties, I couldn't find anything about setting Graph level properties.