# How to Replace EdgeLabel in a Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, replacement

I am working with Graphs in which I want to define a Graph with Symbols or Strings as EdgeLabels, and later replace these with functions of the symbols with symbols then replaced with numerical values. I have tried using Replace without success. I can replace the symbols with numerical values by setting the values of the symbols, but that does not allow for replacing the symbol by a function of the symbol first.

Below are my unsuccessful attempts:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, 
  EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> x, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> y}]

g // FullForm

(*replacements doesn't work*)

values = {x -> 1, y -> 2};

g /. values

(*a more complicated case*)

g /. Rule[DirectedEdge[n1_, n2_], s_] -> 
  Rule[DirectedEdge[n1, n2], 1/s]

(*this does work, but doesn't fulfill the need for more complicated \
replacements*)

x = z;

g
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace expressions inside a Graph object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222060/how-do-i-replace-expressions-inside-a-graph-object) Also: [#4543](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4543/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-change-options-for-graph-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use

```
Graph[g, EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeLabels] /. values]
```

or

```
SetProperty[g, EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeLabels] /. values]
```

to get

[image]

Similarly, for the second example:

```
values2 = Rule[DirectedEdge[n1_, n2_], s_] :> 
   Rule[DirectedEdge[n1, n2], 1/s];

Graph[g, EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeLabels] /. values2]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @kglr